# Import issue for cvxopt on Windows

Tags: python, windows, lapack, cvxopt

I installed `cvxopt` verbatim from [here](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/install/index.html#building-cvxopt-for-windows). On using it from the python prompt, I see the following issue:

```
>>> import cvxopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cvxopt\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cvxopt\base.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\cvxopt\base.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
>>>
```

Any ideas to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

`cvxopt` requires `Numpy-MKL`, you can get the windows binary [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

And   install the `cvxopt` binary from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cvxopt)